# Adding a thin line below selected menu item. Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

can anyone point me in the right direction to add a thin line or icon under the selected menu item for a WP site? Here is an example of what I mean.

http://thehalogroup.com/work/

Comment: You can apply `border-bottom` css property for selected menu item.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways of handling this depending on the visual results you want.

#### Example 1 - Anchor Element

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.example-1 .active a,
.example-1 a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="example-1">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add padding to `<a>` to push the border down if applying border to `<a>` element.

#### Example 2 - Parent Element

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.example-2 .active,
.example-2 li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="example-2">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here the extra spacing comes from the line height of the anchor element instead of padding.

#### Example 3 - Pseudo Element

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.example-3 .active {
  position: relative;
}
.example-3 .active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul class="example-3">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

With a pseudo element you can get a bit more creative with size, location etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

if you want it underlined or

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

if you want it to look like in your example.

Here's a code example
https://jsfiddle.net/1woa1xmm/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html you will see a large number of classes. The class you need is `current-menu-item` just give that a `border-bottom`

So something like

```
.current-menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

You probably want to add extra classes/selector so you only take the top menu.

Comment: If you are using WP4.7 in the customizer there is a setting to app own css.